# How to sort a map of Firebase DocumentReferences by date?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a small chat app using Firebase cloud. I have created the following structure in Firebase database:

```
Collection "users" -> bob@gmail.com document -> map of "chat rooms" field (type Map<String, DocumentReference>)
Collection chatRooms -> room id document -> Collection messages -> message id document -> fields
```

The `message id document` contains the following fields:

```
from: the user that sent the message
message: the text of the mesasage
sentAt: Date
```

I want to create a RecyclerView of all the chat rooms of the current user. So what I did is:

```
FireDB.collection("users").document(connectedEmail).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "addOnSuccessListener:success");
        if (!(documentSnapshot.exists())) {
            // TODO
            return;
        }
        Map<String, DocumentReference> chatRooms = (Map<String, DocumentReference>) documentSnapshot.get("chatRooms");
        if (chatRooms.isEmpty()) {
            // TODO
            return;
        }
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "addOnSuccessListener:failed");
    }
});
```

What would be the easiest way to the chatroom map by the date of the last message? I thought of keeping in the `room id document` level the latest time this document was touched but I want to know if it's possible to do using Firebase without adding special support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You have to update chat room Document whenever a message is sent,
Firebase Firestore doesn't automatically add a timestamp to the write.

Let's say you have field "updated_at" (time in Timestamp) inside the room document,
whenever a message is sent in this room, you just have to update it with the latest timestamp.
Then you can get all the rooms in a particular order.

Why saving time in Timestamp?

0. Firebase Recommends it.
1. It easier to query the documents using the DIRECTION in orderBy
2. Can be converted easily to any date display without much code

Implementation example

```
  FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("YOUR_COLLECTION") 
                .whereEqualTo("your_key", "your_value")
                .orderBy("lastUpdateTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
                if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {

                 //DATA returned, You can use Gson to convert them to your POJO list

                } else {

                    //NO DATA RETURNED

                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: By Timestamp you mean the epoch time from 1970?

Comment: No, Firebase Timestamp. You can have more info here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. So how do I use `.orderBy("lastUpdateTime", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)` here?

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: If I insert that field, how can I iterate over the DocumentReferences and create a sorted map of DocumentReference or Snapshots?

Comment: db.collection('your_col_id'')
  .doc(youdoc_id)
  .orderBy('lastUpdateTime', Query.Direction.DESCENDING').get() will return list of query sanpshots which will in descending order

Comment: But `chatRooms` is a DocumentReferences map. I want to use instead of another query collection

Comment: You can only query collections. Document's data doesn't change the way its collection is queried. DocumentReferece is just an object.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. I understand that but the problem in your solution that it will give me all of the chat rooms and not only the one of the user.

Comment: in that case, whereEqualTo("your_key", "your_value") will help you to get a users to chat room, Where your key is the name of array of user uids, and your_value is the uid of the user. then you can use the arrayContains method to get check if the user you want is in it or not